# Como usar o mesmo texto em vários HTML de modo que eu possa editá-los pelo CSS?

Tags: html, css

Eu tenho vários HTML (mais de 500 HTML) que usarão o mesmo título pra todos, por exemplo: "Projetos de 2017" será o título nos 500 arquivos

Depois vou precisar alterar o título para "Projetos de 2018"

Mas não quero ter o trabalho de abrir todos os 500 html e alterar apenas uma palavra em cada um

O que eu queria era alterar o título em apenas um arquivo e assim alterasse em todos o outros 500 de uma só vez

De que forma eu posso fazer isso usando CSS através do `<link href="*.css" type="text/css" />` ???

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento sem título</title>
<style type="text/css">
.title div:after {
    content: "Andrei webmaster";    
}
.titlecenter {
    text-align: center;
    color: #F00;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="title">
  <div class="titlecenter"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Com CSS não é possível. Com JavaScript, sim, mas você terá que inserir a referência do arquivo em todos os arquivos HTML da mesma forma. A ferramenta "Find/Replace" dos editores de texto não lhe serve?

Comment: Colocar um `include` na página em php para centralizar o título em apenas um arquivo.

Comment: É possível sim. Só não é elegante rs.

Comment: Com css da, mas a única maneira que conheço é usando after ou before {content:"projetos 2018";}. Gostaria de saber se tem outras formas. Não queria usar Javascript

Comment: Por curiosidade: por quê CSS? Qual o motivo de não usar JS ou simplesmente não alterar o valor com "Find/Replace"?

Answer (score 1):

Com puro `css`, dá para você fazer umas gambiarras, mas tem de adaptar no layout, exemplo :

```html
<h1>Projetos de 2017</h1>
<style>
h1{visibility: hidden;}
h1:before{content:"Projetos 2018";visibility: visible;}
</style>
```

Para o seu código ficaria assim, você esqueceu de esconder o primeiro conteúdo com `visibility:hidden` e dependendo da estrutura `before` cai melhor do que `after`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento sem título</title>
<style type="text/css">
.title div{visibility: hidden;}
.title div:after {
    display:block;
    width:250px;
    margin:0 auto;
    content: "Andrei webmaster";
    visibility: visible;
    color: #F00;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.titlecenter {
    text-align:center;
    color: #F00;
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="title">
  <div class="titlecenter">Andrew Stuart Tanenbaum</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Acredito que ele se refere ao título em `<title></title>`, pelo o que eu entendi.

Comment: Não!! Dentro do <body></body> mesmo

Comment: Ta aí o código,  MagicHat. Aí onde está o texto: "Andrei webmaster" é que seria modificado em todos os arquivos html usando ' link href="*.css" ' Preguiça de abrir 500 html =p

Comment: Não tem nada de incremental aí, Leon Freire. É tudo estático mesmo!! Só html e css. Acontece que trabalho em um órgão público onde publico tabelas na web em html com dados estatísticos convertidos de xls para html. Mas todas as tabelas tem o mesmo título no corpo (body). Tinha terminado o trabalho, mas aí os estatísticos daqui me pediram para modificar o título. Daí vou modificar, ok! Mas da próxima vez estarei precavido e vou alterar o titulo das tabelas só de uma vez

Comment: @Andrei se alguma das repostas for correta, considere validá-la... Desta forma outros usuários poderão se beneficiar

Comment: usando o title div{visibility: hidden;}, não percebi muita diferença. Mas a dúvida é se teria uma maneira mais elegante de fazer isso via CSS, mas sem usar " before || after "

Comment: @Andrei Ah mano pra que se quer elegância, fazendo gambiarra ? fui;;;;

Answer (score 1):

Agora que tive uma maior compreensão do seu problema. Posso também recomendar uma solução alternativa. Você pode usar o `ctrl + f` do Notepad++ e simplesmente trocar todas as ocorrências de uma vez sé em todos os arquivos em uma pasta, na terceira opção (Localizar em arquivos).
Acho que como seu problema é simplesmente a preguiça, essa deve ser a forma mais prática! :D

Comment: Uia sabia disso naum...boa...

Comment: @MagicHat É mó mão na roda! Haha..

Answer (score 0):

O ideal para este tipo de tarefa é usar PHP. É muito simples: basta copiar todo o código que deseja alterar posteriormente em um arquivo separado. EX:

```
site
├ index.php
└ page_elements
  └ header.php
```

`<?php require 'page_elements/header.php';?>`

Também é possível realizar isso com JavaScript:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var titulo = document.getElementById("title");
  titulo.innerHTML = "<h1>Novo título</h1>";
}
```

```html
<div id="title">
  <h1>Título inicial</h1>
</div>
```

Uma gambiarra em CSS que não é nada recomendada:

```css
h1{color: transparent}
h1:before{
  display: block;
  content: "Título que gostei";
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #222;
}
```

```html
<h1>Título que não gostei, mas sempre estará lá, caso não use uma linguagem de programação.</h1>
```

Comment: Optei por javascript mesmo. Obrigado à todos